# Build failing for Android after updating xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. Yesterday, I updated Xamarin.Forms package to the latest version 4.8.0.1687. In Visual Studio 2019 I can build the app and run it. But build in Azure DevOps pipeline fails. For Android, the following error is reported:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\My_MobileApp\My_MobileApp\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netstandard2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\My_MobileApp\My_MobileApp\My_MobileApp.csproj]

Where My_MobileApp is the shared project.

I checked the project file, but the Target Framework there is set to .NET Standard 2.0. I checked the project.assets.json in the local obj folder, and it has

```
 "originalTargetFrameworks": [
    "netstandard2.0"
  ],
```

But no "TargetFrameworks".

What is wrong, and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating nuget to 5.8 worked for me

Comment: Same. Make sure you don't specify a nuget version in "Use Nuget" task for latest version or specify it as 5.8.